# Does GoogleMap (in Android.Gms.Map) remove the find direction function?

Tags: android, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.android, direction

I got a trouble with finding direction in GoogleMap in Xamarin Android. I also search alot of articles before asking this question. I just want to input 2 positions (lat, lng) and the map will show me the direction. But I can't find it.

One solution is call an url of google map API, it returns a list of positions. Then we draw some Polyline based on that list. But it's a line that connects 2 positions. And in the real world, the road doesn't a line. And I don't want to do this way.

So, can I find the direction between 2 positions without that way? If I can, how to do it?

Thank you for helping me! And I'm sorry for my english, cuz it's not my native language.

Comment: You can use google directions API which will return you the complete route and it won't be just a line it will be actual route points. URL:  http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=lat,lng&destination=lat,lng&sensor=true&units=metric&mode=driving

Answer (score 1):

Go through [this](https://github.com/jd-alexander/Google-Directions-Android)
example. It worked for me.

Comment: You should not post a link alone as a answer as the link may be delete in future. So add some content in your answer.

Comment: Unlucky, I'm working with xamarin and developing in Visual Studio. It doesn't help! :(

Comment: @NgoKimHuynh did you find a solution as yet ? I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Google Driving Directions - MapView overlayed](http://www.anddev.org/google_driving_directions_-_mapview_overlayed-t826.html). Also go through the [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/).

Comment: I got a list of position already. Then the next step is draw a polyline between them. And that's my problem, polyline doesn't follow the road.